# Getting Percentages In Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a report listing the number of employees that answered specific questions on a survey and it lists the total population. I am trying to get the percentages of the answers to the total population but I am having trouble getting the code to work. So far my code is:

```
SELECT 
Mgmt_Lvl.MGMT_LVL, 
Count(O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR) AS Total, 
Sum(IIf(emp_rlc_ir="Y",1,0)) AS Relocate, 
Sum(IIf(emp_int_asn_ir="Y",1,0)) AS International_Assignment, 
Sum(IIf(emp_tvl_ir="y",1,0)) AS Travel, 
Sum(IIf(emp_spc_asn_ir="y",1,0)) AS Special_Assignment
FROM (O867IA_VPJOBCO 
INNER JOIN Mgmt_Lvl ON O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_GRP_CD = Mgmt_Lvl.JOB_GRP_CD) 
INNER JOIN (O896IA_VEMPPRSA INNER JOIN O867IA_VCAREER 
    ON O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR = O867IA_VCAREER.SYS_EMP_ID_NR) 
ON O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_CLS_CD = O896IA_VEMPPRSA.JOB_CLS_CD
WHERE (((O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_EMT_STS_CD)<>"T"))
GROUP BY Mgmt_Lvl.MGMT_LVL;
```

The SUM(IIF(... are the counts and the TOTAL is the total population. I need to get the SUM(IIF( / TOTAL to get the percentages.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'trouble'? Is it throwing errors or just giving you wrong numbers?  If it would help, you can also edit your post and give an example.

Comment: Also, assuming that the query you gave us works correctly, the simplest approach would be to calculate the percentages in a new query that would use this as your data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aliased field names in other calculated fields of a SELECT query in Access.  The following modified SELECT clause should do what you want:

```
SELECT 
Mgmt_Lvl.MGMT_LVL, 
Count(O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR) AS Total, 
Sum(IIf(emp_rlc_ir="Y",1,0))/Total AS Relocate, 
Sum(IIf(emp_int_asn_ir="Y",1,0))/Total AS International_Assignment, 
Sum(IIf(emp_tvl_ir="y",1,0))/Total AS Travel, 
Sum(IIf(emp_spc_asn_ir="y",1,0))/Total AS Special_Assignment
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your query is working...   wrap it in a subquery.

```
SELECT MGMT_LVL,
       R / TTL AS RelocatePercent,
       I / TTL AS IntlAssgntPercent,
       T / TTL AS TravelPercent,
       S / TTL AS SpecialAssgntPercent
FROM (SELECT Mgmt_Lvl.MGMT_LVL, 
             Count(O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR) AS TTL, 
             Sum(IIf(emp_rlc_ir="Y",1,0)) AS R, 
             Sum(IIf(emp_int_asn_ir="Y",1,0)) AS I, 
             Sum(IIf(emp_tvl_ir="y",1,0)) AS T, 
             Sum(IIf(emp_spc_asn_ir="y",1,0)) AS S
        FROM (O867IA_VPJOBCO 
                INNER JOIN Mgmt_Lvl
                   ON O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_GRP_CD = Mgmt_Lvl.JOB_GRP_CD) 
                INNER JOIN (O896IA_VEMPPRSA INNER JOIN O867IA_VCAREER 
                                               ON O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR = 
                                                  O867IA_VCAREER.SYS_EMP_ID_NR) 
                   ON O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_CLS_CD = O896IA_VEMPPRSA.JOB_CLS_CD
       WHERE (((O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_EMT_STS_CD)<>"T"))
    GROUP BY Mgmt_Lvl.MGMT_LVL) SQ;
```

Comment: That worked Perfectly thank you. Is there a way to get it to just show it to 2 decimal places?

Comment: I would recommend using the Format property of the report or form control where you will be displaying the data: `#.##`.  You could also use the `Round()` function within the query but that will be less efficient.

Comment: Also, there is no need to use a subquery for this.  Access (i.e., the Jet/ACE db engine) is perfectly capable of using an aliased field name as part of another calculated field.  I would expect the subquery approach to hurt performance with a large dataset.

Comment: You are incorrect with your assumption mwolfe02

Just to be sure I tested with both methods against a recordset with 1.6 million records.  In multiple tests, running in various orders - the subquery was at least one whole second faster than the aliased field.   To give you an idea of my specific numbers - the average time for the aliased field was 10.21094 seconds while the average time for the subquery was 8.976563.

In an aliased field situation - Access is running its own subquery behind the scenes.

Comment: Furthermore - by wrapping it in a subquery, the user is now free to do other things such as removing duplicates from the equation.

Comment: @DHW: Benchmarks are king.  Now that I actually think about it, it makes sense that Access would be implementing this via subquery.  Nice work. +1

Comment: I'll admit I'm a bit surprised the difference is that significant (and in that direction).  I'd want to take a look at JETSHOWPLAN to try and sort out the reason why, but I'm not inclined to do that today.  Something I will definitely keep in mind for the future.

Comment: He ended up requiring a subquery approach anyhow in order to remove duplicates.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724925/returning-most-recent-dates-data