# Filter query result by most recent date

Tags: sql, ms-access

This code:

```
SELECT  
    O896IA_VEMPPRSA.REG_NR & O896IA_VEMPPRSA.DIS_NR AS RRDD,  
    Mgmt_Lvl.MGMT_LVL,  
    Count(O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR) AS Total,  
    Sum(IIf(emp_rlc_ir="Y",1,0)) AS Relocate,  
    Sum(IIf(emp_int_asn_ir="Y",1,0)) AS International_Assignment,  
    Sum(IIf(emp_tvl_ir="y",1,0)) AS Travel,  
    Sum(IIf(emp_spc_asn_ir="y",1,0)) AS Special_Assignment,  
    Sum(IIf([emp_rlc_ir]="Y",1,0))/[Total] AS Relocate_Percent,  
    Sum(IIf([emp_int_asn_ir]="Y",1,0))/[Total] AS International_Assignment_Percent,  
    Sum(IIf([emp_tvl_ir]="y",1,0))/[Total] AS Travel_Percent,  
    Sum(IIf([emp_spc_asn_ir]="y",1,0))/[Total] AS Special_Assignment_Percent

FROM (O867IA_VPJOBCO INNER JOIN Mgmt_Lvl  
    ON O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_GRP_CD = Mgmt_Lvl.JOB_GRP_CD)  
INNER JOIN (O896IA_VEMPPRSA INNER JOIN O867IA_VCAREER  
    ON O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR = O867IA_VCAREER.SYS_EMP_ID_NR)  
    ON O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_CLS_CD = O896IA_VEMPPRSA.JOB_CLS_CD

WHERE (((O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_EMT_STS_CD)<>"T"))

GROUP BY  
    O896IA_VEMPPRSA.REG_NR & O896IA_VEMPPRSA.DIS_NR, 
    Mgmt_Lvl.MGMT_LVL,  
    Mgmt_Lvl.Ranking

ORDER BY Mgmt_Lvl.Ranking DESC;
```

gives me survey answers for employees, the problem is this survey is taken every year and I need the most recent years answers.

I tried using the MAX for the REC_EFF_STT_DT but for some employees their answers changed each year so due to the group by (which I need) it still returns multiple years answers.

Is there a solution where I can just pull out the most recent data? It doesn't necessarily have to be 2013 if an employee took the survey in 2008, 2009, and 2010 but not in 2011, 2012, or 2013 then I still want that 2010 data, which ever is the most recent survey they took is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a table named [Survey] with the following data

```
RespondentID    SurveyDate  Answer1                         Answer2
------------    ----------  ----------------------------    ----------------------------
1               2013-01-01  answer 1, respondent 1, 2013    answer 2, respondent 1, 2013
1               2012-01-01  answer 1, respondent 1, 2012    answer 2, respondent 1, 2012
2               2012-01-01  answer 1, respondent 2, 2012    answer 2, respondent 2, 2012
```

You can use a query of the form...

```
SELECT Survey.*
FROM
    Survey
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT RespondentID, MAX(SurveyDate) AS MaxOfSurveyDate
        FROM Survey
        GROUP BY RespondentID
    ) AS MaxDate
        ON Survey.RespondentID = MaxDate.RespondentID
            AND Survey.SurveyDate = MaxDate.MaxOfSurveyDate
```

...to return the most recent row for each respondent, which in this case would be:

```
RespondentID    SurveyDate  Answer1                         Answer2
------------    ----------  ----------------------------    ----------------------------
1               2013-01-01  answer 1, respondent 1, 2013    answer 2, respondent 1, 2013
2               2012-01-01  answer 1, respondent 2, 2012    answer 2, respondent 2, 2012
```